# pyautogui creating screenshot in specific area knowing 2 corners

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have coordinates for 2 corners https://prnt.sc/w2jryh (x and y coordinates for d and b points of the square). And I need to create screenshot within the area of this square, but when I am trying to do that, it is failing, either getting too much in screenshot, or too less. What may be the magic formula for that :) This is what I tried:

```
pyautogui.screenshot("testScr.png",region=(blackRookCornerX,whiteRookCornerY,whiteRookCornerX,blackRookCornerY))
```

basically taking coordinates and trying get the right screenshot. Coordinates are correct here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From their [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-screenshot-function)

> There is also an optional region keyword argument, if you do not want a screenshot of the entire screen. You can pass a four-integer tuple of the left, top, width, and height of the region to capture:

The first two numbers should be the x,y coordinates of the top left corner of where you want to take a shot, the third number is how far right/left to go (in pixels) and the fourth is how far up/down to go (in pixels).

Try this:

```
pyautogui.screenshot("testScr.png", region=(blackRookCornerX, whiteRookCornerY, 100, 100))
```

Start with a broad number like 100 and then slowly whittle away until you have the perfect screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a hotkey to use for each corner, to collect the coordinates; Simply put your mouse in those corners and press each hotkey. Then once you have done that for both corners and have two variables, use those variables for your screenshot.